# Installing a java card applet fails due to RSA keypair generation

Tags: nfc, javacard, globalplatform

I'm trying to install an applet into a J3A040 JCOP card.

As install method I have the following:

```
protected MainApplet() {

    try {
        // CREATE RSA KEYS AND PAIR       
        m_keyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
        // STARTS ON-CARD KEY GENERATION PROCESS
        m_keyPair.genKeyPair();
        // OBTAIN KEY REFERENCES
        m_publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) m_keyPair.getPublic();
        m_privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) m_keyPair.getPrivate();
    } catch (CryptoException c) {
        //this line will give you the reason of problem 
        short reason = c.getReason();
        ISOException.throwIt(reason);       // for check
    }

    register();
}
```

The installation always fails with the following error:

```
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: Install for Install and make selectable failed SW: 6A80
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.installAndMakeSelectable(GlobalPlatform.java:798)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:478)
```

However, if I remove the keypair generation, everything works fine.
I have read the card specifications and it stands:

> . RSA and RSA CRT (1280 up to 2048 bits keys) for en-/decryption and
>   signature generation and verification1 d. RSA CRT key generation (1280
>   up to 2048 bits keys) in a secured environment

I guess it shouldn't be a problem.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by an invalid cast: you asked for an RSA KeyPair with the private key in the Chinese Reminder Theorem format (`ALG_RSA_CRT`).

That is why the `getPrivate()` method does not return an `RsaPrivateKey` instance, but an `RsaPrivateCrtKey` instance. Casting to `RsaPrivateKey` causes the `6A80` status word.

So you should either use the standard algorithm:

```
m_keyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
```

, or use a correct cast:

```
m_publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) m_keyPair.getPublic();
m_privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) m_keyPair.getPrivate();
```